# How to delete elements with just emojis in a dictionary with Python

Tags: python, dictionary, emoji

When I have a dict like:

```
dict = {'xyz': 'Sooo ein schönes Bild von dir ', 'xyz2': '✨✨✨', 'xyz3': 'toll, super schön'}
```

How can I use "emoji" to just find the element with emojis only (namely here the value of key xyz2) and delete it from the dict?

I use the emoji module for Python. https://pypi.org/project/emoji/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First consider how to detect emoji with the 'official' `emoji` package function `demojize`. It can decode emojis inside the string into tokens, so we only need to detect are there any non-token elements. Each token is a string that starts and ends with a colon, for example :smile: or :heart:. So if demojized string does not start from token(semicolon), or a token is followed by non token - that's sign of non emoji presence.

```
def are_emojis(s):
    s = s.replace(":", "x")  #  colons from the original text might intefere with token markup
    s = emoji.demojize(s)
    if not s.startswith(':') or len(s) < 3:
        return False     # first symbol is not emoji
    s = s[1:-1] # drop the initial and the last colon
    s = s.replace("::", "")  # delete double colons
    return ":" not in s


for k in list(d):
    if are_emojis(d[k]):
        del d[k]
```

Probably, a more intuitive solution would be to use non-documented regex emoji matcher from that package, or, for simple cases even the list of emoji as below

```
from emoji import UNICODE_EMOJI


def is_emoji(s):
    return s in UNICODE_EMOJI


for k in list(dict):
    if all(map(is_emoji, dict[k])):
        del dict[k]
```

Regretfully, it fails in the case of multi-symbol emoji sequences, when emoji are used along with modifiers or combiner, for example skin color or zero width joiner. A workaround is to add combiners and modifier into that emoji list, but then program will also delete strings which consist only of modifiers and combiners. Better approach it to use `emoji` package regex.

If you prefer build new dictionary without some elements see recipes at https://thispointer.com/python-filter-a-dictionary-by-conditions-on-keys-or-values/

Comment: Does that do a linear search? How many values are in `UNICODE_EMOJI`?

Comment: Is it safe to delete keys from a `dict` while iterating over said `dict`.

Comment: No idea. Did not try to run it myself. Not even sure that constant name is correct. If too many emojis, may be use set. Package has regex for emojis not sure is it any better.

Comment: thx - I am not sure what happens, but I got "RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration" ?

Comment: try now - see Peter comment on dict iteration

Comment: it works, but sometimes it seems to overjump "emoji-only"-items in the first 3 elements.

Comment: Could give examples? Maybe some non-emoji symbols or modifier creeped in?

Comment: it was everytime in the first occuring elements (1-4), like 3 hearts or 2 smileys with stars in the eyes - and they were not deleted from the new dict without the "emoji-only"-items

Comment: It works with the example that you provided even though it has only 3 keys. But maybe try emoji regex

Comment: If something stops you from sharing the strings that are jumped over, you can debug themself and figure which symbols are not included in the emoji list. If unfamiliar with debugging try somethin like `{ s: 'non-emoji' for s in ''✨✨✨" if s not  in UNICODE_EMOJI]`. Personally I suspect the diamonds are not emoji but pictograms and smile face contains some color modifiers

Comment: actually it jumps over several emoji-only-items, like
"❤️❤️❤️❤️❤️❤️❤️❤️❤️❤️', "❤️", "✔️" - but it finds items like "" and delete it - what are "emoji regex"? have I to add all emoji combinations the script doesn't find manually?

Comment: Perhaps. These strings involve invisible characters, which are technically non-emoji (try iterate over strings yourselves to see which characters are there). I would recommend you first try regex available in `emoji` module though they are not always bullet proof too, read more https://github.com/mathiasbynens/emoji-regex/issues/28

Comment: Actually tried to sketch solution with more 'legit' emoji function 'demojise'